# How to display bitmap image after clicking on listview item

Tags: android, bitmap

I am very new to android programming. I am working on my first app.

I am trying to display an image saved in res/drawable-mdpi underneath a short line of text that comes from a listview in a previous activity. For example there is a listview with TV show names when clicked on would have the name of the TV show followed by an image of that TV show. I have tried many different things but here is the basic code I'm working with. The text loads it in but I want the image underneath.

```
package com.example.listviews;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LocationActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("valueLoc");

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

   //     ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_settings);

    setContentView(textView);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should build a listview:

```
//Initialize the programs array
String[]  programsArray = new String[10];

... /* Fill programsArray */

listView = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.programlistview );
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, programArray);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {             
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        /* Code to show image */        
    }
});
```

I can't suggest you any code to show image because the question for this part is too general and the code depends how you want show the image. You can use a Popup, an other Activity, a frame in the same Activity and more.